# Access - How to display field names that meet a condition as a list in a report

Tags: ms-access, report

I am currently working on a project that identifies invasive plant species for 50 sites on an island.  There are 500+ species that may occur in any site, and many of the sites harbor 100 or more of the same species.  I need to list all of the species that occur at each site and I think it would be wildly inefficient to have a separate table for each site, since most sites have many of the same species.  So, I created a table that has all of the species identified for all sites in the first column, all of the sites as column names, and the body of the table with binary data; a "Y" or "N" indicating if a species was identified at the respective site.  Example:

```
 Scientific Name         Old Wives Beach    Dadi      Orote N Airstrip
 Abelmoschus moschatus   N                  N         N
 Abrus precatorius       Y                  N         Y
 Abutilon indicum        N                  N         N
```

What I cannot figure out is an efficient way to display these data in a report in Access.  The problem is that the meaningful data in this table is actually in the column names and not a part of the table that Access pulls from to create a report.  Is there a way to list in a report in Access, the column names (Species) for each record (site) for which there is a "Y"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize your data. Storing sites as columns will be problematic, as you have seen.
**Create a table for species:**

```
Id
ScientificName
other data
```

**Other table for sites:**

```
Id
Name
```

**And a 3th table to relate above tables: SpeciesInSites**

```
SpecieId
SiteId
AnyOtherUsefulData
```

With this data structure you'll be able to get reports, summaries, etc. Also, if you need to report the sites as columns you can use a [pivot query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) or [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-an-Access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752).

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant solution but here's what I would try. This only works if you are trying to run a report for a single site. If you want a 50 page report that has each site on a separate page this will not work.

Create a form with the sites as a dropdown list the user selects and a launch button to open the report. Then use this algorithm to launch the report:

sub ReportMakerclick()

sitename = combobox.value

sql = "SELECT FirstColumn From YourTable WHERE " & sitename & " = ""Y"" "

Update the recordsource of the Report to be sql

Launch the report

end sub